# Android studio - Gradle update failing

Tags: python, android, kivy, apk

I made an android app using Kivy and Buildozer and now I have a signed released version that I would like to publish in the Google Play Store. I tried to convert my apk file using Android Studio but Gradle version is outdated. When I choose to upgrade it in the warning popup, nothing happens. Is there a solution ? Maybe there is also a better/easier way to convert apk into aab ?

Thanks !

Comment: Gradle script ?

Comment: If all you need is to create an aab, call `./gradlew bundleRelease`